# Plotting multiple plots and text with networkx and matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex, networkx

I am calling the function `nx.draw` to plot a graph eg:

[image]

I would like to make a plot that graphs three such graphs in a line, with a `=` and `\cup` symbol in between to symbolize that one is the union of the other two.

For example something like this:

[image]

How can I make this with matplotlib?

I tried

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G=nx.grid_2d_graph(1,5)
plt.subplot(151)
draw_model(composite_argument)
ax = plt.subplot(152)
ax.text(60, 60,"=")
ax.set_xlim(0, 100)
ax.set_ylim(0, 100)
plt.subplot(153)
draw_model(argument1)
ax = plt.subplot(154)
ax.text(60, 60,"U")
ax.set_xlim(0, 100)
ax.set_ylim(0, 100)
plt.subplot(155)
draw_model(argument2)
```

which results in a very weird plot

[image]

Comment: @JohanC ah my bad! It just calls nx.draw with some parameters I hardcoded. I have updated the question to make it clearer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are clearly doing something wrong inside `draw_model()`. Maybe you call `plt.figure()` or `plt.show()`?

Anyway, the recommended way to create subplots is via `plt.subplots(...)`. And the recommended way to let networkx draw into a subplot is via `nx.draw(...., ax=...)`.

Note that, by default, a subplot has axis limits 0 and 1 both in x and in y direction.  Many plotting functions automatically update the axis limits, but `ax.text()` doesn't (which enables annotations close to the borders without moving them).

Here is some example code.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx

fig, axs = plt.subplots(ncols=5, figsize=(14, 4), gridspec_kw={'width_ratios': [4, 1, 4, 1, 4]})

nx.draw_circular(nx.complete_graph(5), ax=axs[0])

axs[1].text(0.5, 0.5, '<', size=50, ha='center', va='center')
axs[1].axis('off')

nx.draw_circular(nx.complete_graph(7), ax=axs[2])

axs[3].text(0.5, 0.5, '<', size=50, ha='center', va='center')
axs[3].axis('off')

nx.draw_circular(nx.complete_graph(9), ax=axs[4])

plt.show()
```

[image: networkx plots into subplots]